# Partial Chu-Vandermonde summation $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k/2-1} {n/4 \choose i}{3n/4 \choose k-i}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Could someone help me find a **tight** upper bound for the following:
$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k/2-1} {n/4 \choose i}{3n/4 \choose k-i}$

It's essentially a Chu-Vandermonde summation of only the first $k/2$ terms so it's clearly upper bounded by ${n \choose k}$, but I'd like to know how fast it approaches ${n \choose k}$ as a function of k.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mathematica says this here $$\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma
   (-k+n+1)}-\binom{\frac{n}{4}}{\frac{k}{2}} \binom{\frac{3 n}{4}}{\frac{k}{2}}
   \,
   _3F_2\left(1,-\frac{k}{2},\frac{k}{2}-\frac{n}{4};\frac{k}{2}+1,-\frac{k}{2}+
   \frac{3 n}{4}+1;1\right)$$ which containes a hypergeometric function

Comment: I was hoping for something simpler :)

Comment: i someone has a simplier result?